# Dynamic where clauses lambda or query in C#

Tags: c#, entity-framework, dynamic, lambda

I am trying to write a dynamic lambda or query but it occurs an error..

for lambda; I created a function

```
    public IEnumerable<musteriler>  GetCustomers<musteriler>(Expression<Func<musteriler, bool>> where)
   {
    IEnumerable<musteriler> _musteriler = market.musteriler.Where(where).Select(m => m);

     return _musteriler;

    }
```

and I call like that

```
  IEnumerable<musteriler> _musteriler  = helper.GetCustomers<musteriler>(m => m.MAktif == true);
```

I get two errors in Where(**where**) which are

```
    The best overloaded method match for System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery<AkilliMarket.musteriler>.Where(string, params System.Data.Objects.ObjectParameter[])' has some invalid arguments
```

and

```
   Argument 1: cannot convert from 'System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<System.Func<musteriler,bool>>' to 'string'
```

after I tried a string query like

```
 IEnumerable<musteriler> _musteriler=  market.musteriler.Where("MAktif = true").Select(m => m) as IEnumerable<musteriler>;
```

yes it works but I cant use _musteriler.. for example when I write _musteriler.Count(); I get this error

```
  'MAktif' could not be resolved in the current scope or context. Make sure that all referenced variables are in scope, that required schemas are loaded, and that namespaces are referenced correctly. Near simple identifier, line 6, column 1.
```

MAktif is a column name of my musteriler table in db. and I tried another columns but result is same..

Where are my mistakes for both?

Comment: market is my database which connected datamodel. and i defined it as   private AkilliMarketEntities market;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is `IQueryable<T>.Where` is an extension method and `ObjectQuery.Where` is picked as "best overloaded method match" before extension methods are considered.

Try:

```
public IEnumerable<AkilliMarket.musteriler> GetCustomers<AkilliMarket.musteriler>(Expression<Func<AkilliMarket.musteriler, bool>> predicate)
{
   return market.musteriler.AsQueryable().Where(predicate);
}
```

Comment: similar error  Error 1 The best overloaded method match for 'System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery<AkilliMarket.musteriler>.Where(string, params System.Data.Objects.ObjectParameter[])' has some invalid arguments Error 2 Argument 1: cannot convert from 'System.Func<musteriler,bool>' to 'string'

Comment: Do you have `using System.Linq` like @Ladislav suggested?

Comment: yes I have... my all references are using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

Comment: no again... Error 2 Argument 2: cannot convert from 'System.Func<musteriler,bool>' to 'System.Func<AkilliMarket.musteriler,int,bool>'          Error 1 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<AkilliMarket.musteriler>' does not contain a definition for 'Where' and the best extension method overload 'System.Linq.Enumerable.Where<TSource>(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<TSource>, System.Func<TSource,int,bool>)' has some invalid arguments

Comment: @HarunAbi well, at least it's trying the extension methods now. See the edit.

Comment: thank you very much Eren. I found where is mistake with your code.. Func<AkilliMarket.musteriler, bool>   I wrote like just "musteriler" instead of AkilliMarket.musteriler .. and it was problem.. thank you problem solved

Comment: Do not use `AsEnumerable()` here, use `AsQueryable()`. AsEnumerable will cause the whole table to load into memory, before applying the "Where()".

Comment: @HansKesting, thank you for useful suggestion.. I will consider it.

Answer (score 1):

```
public IEnumerable<musteriler>  GetCustomers<musteriler>(Expression<Func<musteriler, bool>> predicate)
       {
        return market.musteriler.AsQueryable().Where(predicate).AsEnumerable();

        }
```

if it doesn't work

can you just try

```
 var _musteriler=  market.musteriler.Where("it.MAktif = @val", new ObjectParameter("val", true)).AsEnumerable().Count();
```

and if it works, your method should be (if there's still a sense to make a method)

```
public IEnumerable<musteriler> GetCustomers(string whereClause, params ObjectParameter[] parameters) {
   return market.musteriler.Where(whereClause, parameters).AsEnumerable(); 
}
```

Comment: thank for your nice answer but I get same error. because the problem is not about return type.. it shows problem is in predicate..  and same error which I post in my first message

Comment: using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

Comment: thank you Raphael, your second code works too :) thank you very much for your interesting..

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need to add this at the beginning of your code:

```
using System.Linq;
```

It looks like your market is `ObjectContext` and musteriler is `ObjectSet` and it doesn't provide Where accepting lambda - you need extension Where method on `IQueryable` which accepts lambda expression.

Comment: yest market is an objectcontext.. and could you give me a sample for it ?

Answer (score -1):

In the example I was trying , I was getting the error,

> No overload for method 'Where' takes 3 arguments

with my where clause expression using SQLParametera.

I found that I needed

> using System.Linq.Dynamic;
>   once I discovered it, DUH

Comment: This has nothing to do with the question asked here.