# How to build a filter with LINQ

Tags: linq, filter

I have a form with a grid that show for example all the products of a company. Also I have a some fields and combos boxes to permit user to select what he want filter for, for example, filter for product name, type of product, etc... Note that he can combine product name and type of product, etc.... Also these fields can be leave empty or not selected (combos), so I have to do a LINQ query to filter the products in the grid from what user has tried to filter. As there are several fields and combos that compose the filter, how to achiever this?
how to build this query?

Thanks.

Comment: Look in the "Related" section on the right hand side and search. This has been asked a lot of times already.

Comment: check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11014017/dynamic-where-clauses-lambda-or-query-in-c-sharp

Answer (score 0):

If the structure of the query form remains the same, you can build a single large condition that ignores restrictions on fields that have not been set:

```
decimal? minPrice = ...;
decimal? maxPrice = ...;
string prodName = ...;
bool noName = string.IsNullOrWhitespace(prodName);
string prodType = ...;
bool noType = string.IsNullOrWhitespace(prodType);
var filteredProducts = context
    .AllProducts
    .Where(p =>
        (!minPrice.HasValue || p.Price >= minPrice.Value)
    &&  (!maxPrice.HasValue || p.Price <= maxPrice.Value)
    &&  (noName || p.Name == prodName)
    &&  (noType || p.Type == prodType)
    );
```